# "Unrecognized option: --add-opens" Hyperledger Besu

Tags: java, windows, hyperledger

I want to get started with Hyperledger Besu, after following the steps of the [official documentation here](https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/HowTo/Get-Started/Starting-node/) and running the following command:

`bin\besu --help`

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\besu-1.3.9>bin\besu --help
Unrecognized option: --add-opens
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I get the same thing when running `bin\besu` or `bin\besu -help`.

I don't know if the problem is with java's installation or with hyperledger besu trying to run unvalid/unrecognised option `bin\besu --add-opens`. I tried uninstalling then reinstalling java but this did not solve the issue, here is java's version:

```
C:\Users\user>java -version
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512m
java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `--add-opens` is part of [project jigsaw](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/), which was released with Java 9.

Comment: I see, thank you for the info @Turing85 . Then why I'm getting ```Unrecognized option: --add-opens```, what shoul I do?

Comment: .. update to at least Java 9. Or - as the software's websiets states, Java 11.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have no prior experience with the library that is in discussion, but I have just had a look at the [official docs](https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/HowTo/Get-Started/Install-Binaries/) of the library that you are trying to use, and the installation instructions state that you require `Java 11+` to compile

> Hyperledger Besu requires:
>
> MacOS High Sierra **10.13** or **later** versions
>
> **Java 11+ to compile**; earlier versions are not supported.

From your question, it looks like your system is running Java8. Try bumping it up to `Java 11` and try starting the binary again.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I installed Java 13.0.2 from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk11-downloads.html) and didn't get the error again.

Answer (score 3):

change the java home version path from jdk8 path to jdk11 in environment variable
as
JAVA_HOME : {jdk11 directory path}

Answer (score 1):

The script you're running adds `--add-opens java.base/sun.security.provider=ALL-UNNAMED` to the java command line that starts Besu. As others have noted, the `--add-opens` parameter was made available in Java 9; all it does is prevent a warning from being issued when any class uses reflection to access an internal JDK class (in this case, the Sun security package). I've been starting Besu *without* this parameter for weeks with no problems, so you could have simply removed the parameter from the Besu start script or -- better -- upgraded to at least the Java 11 or higher version that Besu expects. According to Oracle, this command line parameter will be removed eventually, but that's a problem for the Besu maintainers, not you.

Comment: This parameter will **not** be removed, and those warnings have now turned into errors starting with Java 16. Java 17 did remove `--illegal-access` through.

Answer (score 0):

> Simple Solution if one is using Tomcat to deploy their project. Go to
> the Run Configuration of Tomcat. Find this argument and remove the
> same. No need to change the Java path if you still want to use Java 8.

Answer (score -1):

1)You can change the JAVA_HOME variable to at least Java 9 but official document says "Java 11+ to compile; earlier versions are not supported."

**To set JAVA_HOME, do the following:**
Right click My Computer and select Properties.
On the Advanced tab, select Environment Variables
Then edit JAVA_HOME to point to where the JDK software is located,
for example, C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_341

2)Or You can change the version of the JRE used by the local tomcat server from the Server runtime environment section.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34487176)