Intellij Java 8 issue on run - Unrecognized option: --add-opens
I installed latest intellij and i want to run a java 8 project, i am using latest version of maven and the build install is working fine but once i run the project, i get Unrecognized option: --add-opens. i tried to modify the project settings to point to java 8 everywhere even JAVA_HOME, i even tried with lower maven version and same issue. can anyone help? to note that the same project was running fine on my other laptop using previous intellij versions.

Intellij version: ntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.1 (Community Edition)
Deatils:
      Abnormal build process termination: 
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Djna.boot.library.path=C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/lib/jna/amd64" 
-Djna.nosys=true -Djna.noclasspath=true --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens 
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED 
--add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens 
jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED -Dpreload.project.path=C:/Users/xx/Desktop/Files/intellijNewWorkspace/multichannelaccountsws 
-Dpreload.config.path=C:/Users/xx/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.1/options -Dexternal.project.config=C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2024.1\projects\multichannelaccountsws.6c161493\external_build_system
 -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Didea.IntToIntBtree.page.size=32768 -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false 
 -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=6462762080247829856 -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.language=fr -Duser.country=FR -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2024.1 
 "-Didea.home.path=C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1" -Didea.config.path=C:/Users/xx/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.1 
 -Didea.plugins.path=C:/Users/xx/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.1/plugins -Djps.log.dir=C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.1/log/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/jbr" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=17.0.10 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.1/compile-server/multichannelaccountsws_e2891c5c/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true "-Djps.kotlin.home=C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc" -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"C:\Users\xx~1.BAD\AppData\Local\Temp\kotlin-idea-12919414214725870895-is-running\" -Dide.propagate.context=false -classpath "C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/lib/util-8.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/lib/util_rt.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/lib/platform-loader.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/lib/annotations.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/lib/trove.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/java/lib/jetbrains.kotlinx.metadata.jvm.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/lib/protobuf.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/lib/jps-model.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/lib/forms_rt.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/lib/util.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/lib/idea_rt.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/lib/util-8.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/platform-langInjection/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar;C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.1/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 56654 4f28fb3d-4fd5-49d2-b3c0-e12c70eeb279 C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.1/compile-server
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: --add-opens


seems like you'll have to update to a later version. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60353491/unrecognized-option-add-opens-hyperledger-besu

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

you mean that i should downgrade intellij? what is requiring java 11 precisely?

The module system (of which the option add-opens is a part) was not available in java 8. It seems you try to pass it to a jdk1.8.0_202. We cannot tell exactly which module(s) IntelliJ tries to add, because your image doesn't contain the full path. For such issues, please always add the exact versions of the tools you are using.

I added more details

What project type is it? Maven/Gradle? Please provide more info about your project. If you are using Java 8 to build a project, anything configured to compiler params use --add-opens will cause the javac/java process to crash, it's nothing about the IDEA's own JDK. Some user have put their pom.xml to add these params causing the project can't be built under Java 8.

Can you use a version of IntelliJ bringing its own Java Runtime?

You need to use at least Java 17 to run a recent version of Intellij.  As the documentation says.

"Please note that all the current IDE versions require at least Java 17 version to run. Our IDEs will not run on the older Java versions like Java 8 or 11."

(Emphasis added.)
Source: IDEs Support (IntelliJ Platform) | JetBrains | Selecting the JDK version the IDE will run under.
UPDATE
You commented:

... it is mentioned that version 8 is supported

You found the Supported Java versions and features page in the documentation that lists versions going back to Java 7.  But that does NOT say what you think it says.  It is actually listing the target Java versions (and features) you can use for your applications.  It says:

This page lists all Java versions and preview features supported by IntelliJ IDEA for developing applications. ...

It is NOT talking (there) about the Java version supported to run Intellij itself; i.e. the "boot Java runtime".  (And the evidence bears this out.)

Unrecognized option: --add-opens

In your case, the IDE is failing to launch on Java 8 because the Intellij IDE needs to use the Java modules feature.
Modules are not supported by the Java 8 platform: they were intro in Java 9.  Indeed, if you tried to work around the unsupported option issue by removing all options related to modules from the launch script, the IDE launch would still fail.  It won't work.  Period.


To note that the same project was running fine on my other laptop using previous intellij versions.

Your only options are:

Install the older version of Intellij that worked with Java 8.
Upgrade your laptop to Java 171.
Use your other laptop.


1 - Actually, it is a bit odd that you are using Java 8 at all.  According to the page I linked to above.  Recent versions of Intellij are bundled with a compatible version of Java.  But clearly something about your setup means that you are not using >that< version.  Maybe there are clues in the rest of that page that would help you.

in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/supported-java-versions.html#2023 it is mentioned that version 8 is supported

@user666 IntelliJ can still use Java 8 in a project, but to run IntelliJ itself, you need Java 17. That said, as far as I'm aware, IntelliJ normally uses its own JRE to run itself (at least, on Windows), so I'm not sure what you did for it run with something other than its own JRE. It sounds like you modified the IntelliJ config to try and run IntelliJ itself on Java 8, instead of configuring your IntelliJ project to use a Java 8 JDK.

i reverted to an older intellij version until i migrate from java 8 thank you
